# What is the proper way to structure an optional react date field feeding a django rest framework model?

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, react-redux

I have a django rest framework datetime field (marked null=true, blank=true) which is being fed from a react form field. Currently if I leave the (react) form field blank it causes an error upon submit to the DRF backend (understandable as the react state has it as an empty string, and thus not null). I get around this by overrriding the submitted date field as null if the form field is empty. I would like to know if there is a better or more standard way to do this, as this method seems a little clunky.

models.py

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

React form component

```js
export class Record extends Component {
  state = {
    my_date: "",
  };

  onChange = e => this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

  onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { my_date } = this.state;
    const record = {
      my_date:
        my_date === "" ? null : moment(my_date).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm")
    };
    this.props.addRecord(record);
  };

  <form render code>
```

Comment: why not directly initialize date state as null instead of blank string

Comment: I tried that. I get "Warning: `value` prop on `input` should not be null. Consider using an empty string to clear the component or `undefined` for uncontrolled components."